# How can I block a port being used by docker?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I am running wikijs on port 8080 running reverse proxy with apache. With cloudflare argo tunnel so only specific people can login to wikijs.

So if user try to browse http://publicip:80 (port being used by apache) it will redirect to port 8080 and cloudflare main page will pop up.

However when user try to access directly http://publicip:8080 (port being used by wikijs), it still goes through. Tried ufw with port 80 not being allowed and it works. But not for port 8080

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix here https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker; the current ufw does not block the docker port publicly. There was a change needed in /etc/ufw/after.rules.

Modify the UFW configuration file /etc/ufw/after.rules and add the following rules at the end of the file:

```
# BEGIN UFW AND DOCKER
*filter
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-docker-logging-deny - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-user-forward

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 172.16.0.0/12
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 192.168.0.0/16

-A DOCKER-USER -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -j RETURN

-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 192.168.0.0/16
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 172.16.0.0/12
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 192.168.0.0/16
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 172.16.0.0/12

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

-A ufw-docker-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW DOCKER BLOCK] "
-A ufw-docker-logging-deny -j DROP

COMMIT
# END UFW AND DOCKER
```

Comment: What was the fix, exactly?

Comment: current ufw does not block the docker port publicly. there was a change needed in /etc/ufw/after.rules

Comment: ... could you [edit] your post and describe that change? Certainly we can keep the link to the source (and credit it), but answers here should be self-contained and say more than "make a change in /etc/ufw/after.rules", because that text by itself doesn't tell future readers what to actually change. Thank you!